# Opa5: cannot read property "iLookAtTheScreen" of undefined

Tags: sapui5

So I'm writing my first test in `Opa5` and I get this error, when I call the `iLookAtTheScreen` function to a page. I have a `Worklist` test to a page and a `WorklistJourney` which calls the test functions.

WorklistJourney:

```
    QUnit.module("TabBar");

    opaTest("Should see all the toolbar buttons", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();

        //Actions
        When.onTheWorklistPage.iLookAtTheScreen();

        // Assertions
        Then.onTheWorklistPage.theTabBarShouldHaveAllTheButtons().
            and.iTeardownMyAppFrame();
    });

}
```

Here when I call the `iLookAtTheScreen()` function it says that `onTheWorklistPage` is undefined. I do have an `onTheWorklistPage` segment in the `Worklist.js` file. I have no idea what's the problem.